# Value type field required in Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, knockout.js

I have an enum type field called `Title`.

```
[Serializable]
public enum Title
{
  NotSet,
  Miss = 4,
  Mr = 1,
  Mrs = 3,
  Ms = 2
}
```

I want to bind a property of type `Title` to the Razor View but I don't want it to be a required field. However, on tabbing out or OnBlur, it is showing as required, although I have **not specified** this as `required`.

Is there any way I can get around this?

Comment: An enum must have a value which is why its required. You can always make it nullable - `public Title? Title { get; set; }`

Comment: Why don't you add this CORRECT comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create

```
  namespace YourApplicationName.Helper
     {
  public class ModelValueListProvider : IEnumerable<SelectListItem>
  {
    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> innerList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    public static readonly ModelValueListProvider TitleList = new TitleListProvider();
    protected void Add(string value, string text)
    {
        string innerValue = null, innerText = null;

        if (value != null)
            innerValue = value.ToString();
        if (text != null)
            innerText = text.ToString();

        if (innerList.Exists(kvp => kvp.Key == innerValue))
            throw new ArgumentException("Value must be unique", "value");

        innerList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(innerValue, innerText));
    }
    public IEnumerator<SelectListItem> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new ModelValueListProviderEnumerator(innerList.GetEnumerator());
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    private struct ModelValueListProviderEnumerator : IEnumerator<SelectListItem>
    {
        private IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, string>> innerEnumerator;

        public ModelValueListProviderEnumerator(IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, string>> enumerator)
        {
            innerEnumerator = enumerator;
        }

        public SelectListItem Current
        {
            get
            {
                var current = innerEnumerator.Current;
                return new SelectListItem { Value = current.Key, Text = current.Value };
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            try
            {
                innerEnumerator.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }

        object System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get
            {
                return Current;
            }
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            return innerEnumerator.MoveNext();
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            innerEnumerator.Reset();
        }
    }
   private class TitleListProvider : ModelValueListProvider
    {
        public TitleListProvider (string defaultText = null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(defaultText))
                Add(string.Empty, defaultText);

            Add(Title.NotSet, "NotSet");
            Add(Title.Miss , "Miss");
            Add(Title.Mr , "Mr");
            Add(Title.Mrs , "Mrs");
            Add(Title.MS, "MS");


        }
        public void Add(Title value, string text)
        {
            Add(value.ToString("d"), text);
        }
    }
  }
 }
```

in your model

```
    public Title? Titleformation { get; set; }
    public string[] SelectedTitle { get; set; }
```

in your view, also add the name space to your view

```
     @using YourApplicationName.Helper;
  @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedTitle , new SelectList(ModelValueListProvider.TitleList, "Value", "Text"))
```

hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

Enums require values, and cannot be null (aka not set) despite what someone commented above. What I do for salutations is have a "none" member of the enum, and whenever I print this out, I just check in the code to see if the value of the enum is > 0 (aka, the none option) and don't print it.

```
public enum Salutation { none, 
                         [Description("Mr.")] Mr, 
                         [Description("Mrs.")] Mrs, 
                         [Description("Ms.")]Ms, 
                         [Description("Miss")] Miss }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a class rather than enum ie:

```
public class Title
{
    NotSet;
    Miss = 4;
    Mr = 1;
    Mrs = 3;
    Ms = 2;
}
```

Comment: -1: Apart from not making sense, this code doesn't even compile.